# In phpunit, how can I check the destination url for my validation failed redirect? (Laravel, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, phpunit

My form validation is failing and I'm getting redirected back with error messages.
In phpunit, how can I check the destination url for my validation failed redirect?

When I try to check $response redirect url like so

```
$response->assertRedirect($url);
```

I'm getting error:

> Response status code [422] is not a redirect status code.

Here an example of how the redirect url can be set

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

$validationException = new ValidationException($validator);
$validationException->redirectTo($redirectUrl);
```

How can it be tested?

Comment: is it possible that you are using a ajax request, if so the error status code will always be 422 so you can assert: `$response->assertStatus(422)`

Comment: you are right, thank you. I was using `$response = $this->json('POST', $route, [` instead of `$response = $this->post($route, [` once I switched to `post` the function `$response->assertLocation($url);` started working.

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
$response = $this->json('POST', $route, [...
```

instead of

```
$response = $this->post($route, [...
```

once I switched to `post` the function

```
$response->assertLocation($url);
```

started working.